# How to add header to http response in Spring HandlerInterceptorAdapter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application, I'm trying to add a header to my response in the `afterCompletion()` method of my `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` class.

The controller returns a `ResponseEntity<MyResource>` object such as:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(mr, HttpStatus.OK);
```

following a `POST` request.

In the interceptor, when I try to add a header to the response, it does not get added.

However, when I change my controller to return a response as this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
```

Then it works.

Why would I be able to add a header only when the response body is absent?

Is there a way to add it when the response body is present?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor

Comment: Note that the `afterCompletion` method of `HandlerInterceptor` is not always ideally suited for use with `@ResponseBody` and `ResponseEntity` methods. In such cases an `HttpMessageConverter` writes to and commits the response before `afterCompletion` is called which makes it impossible to change the response, for example to add a header. Instead an application can implement `ResponseBodyAdvice` and either declare it as an `@ControllerAdvice` bean or configure it directly on `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by Ali Deghani, I was pointed in the right direction, and created a new class that extends the `AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice` class (which implements `ResponseBodyAdvice` underneath).

I also got a hint from http://cubiccow.blogspot.co.za/2014/10/api-versioning-of-rest-services.html

This allowed me to successfully modify the response with a new header, based on certain conditions, after it was processed by the controller.